# Test using fake if a method logs an error when an exception is thrown within that method

Tags: unit-testing, fakeiteasy

`enter code here`I have a method that logs errors when an exception is thrown within that method.
The method is non-static inside a singleton.

```
    public object MethodA()
    {
        try
        {
            //code
                             SomeObj.Print(); //updated
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

The unit test code below throws NullreferenceException:

```
                    var fakeLogger = A.Fake<ILog>();

        MySingleton.Instance.Initialize(fakeLogger);

        A.CallTo(() => MySingleton.Instance.MethodA()
            .Invokes((x) => { throw new Exception(); });
               //.Throws(new Exception()); --even this doesnt work
        A.CallTo(() => fakeLogger.Error(A<object>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();


Stack trace:
at FakeItEasy.Creation.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyInterceptionValidator.GetReasonForWhyMethodCanNotBeIntercepted(MethodInfo method)
at FakeItEasy.Creation.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyInterceptionValidator.MethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget, String& failReason)
at FakeItEasy.Creation.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyGenerator.MethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget, String& failReason)
at FakeItEasy.Creation.ProxyGeneratorSelector.MethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget, String& failReason)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.DefaultInterceptionAsserter.AssertThatMethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationManager.AssertThatMemberCanBeIntercepted(LambdaExpression callSpecification)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo(Expression`1 callSpecification)
at FakeItEasy.A.CallTo(Expression`1 callSpecification)
```

Solution:
I had to make my non-fake method throw an exception and this is how I did.

```
var fakeLogger = A.Fake<ILog>();
var someObject = A.Fake<SomeObject>();
MySingleton.Instance.Initialize(fakeLogger);
A.CallTo(() => someObject.Print()).Throws(new Exception()); //key
MySingleton.Instance.MethodA();
A.CallTo(() => fakeLogger.Error(A<object>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MySingleton.Instance` doesn't point to your fake, you have faked an `ILog`, not a `MySingleton`, you can only configure methods on your fake.

For example:

```
A.CallTo(() => fakeLogger.MethodA()).Throws(new Exception());
```

You have to figure out some other way to raise an exception inside your try catch-block.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
A.CallTo(() => MySingleton.Instance.MethodA()).Throws(new Exception());
MySingleton.Instance.MethodA();
A.CallTo(() => fakeLogger.Error(A<object>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: Still gives me a null reference exception on line "A.CallTo(() => MySingleton.Instance.MethodA()).Throws(new Exception());"

Comment: Umm...is MySingleton.Instance null?